JSON String compression in apex
I have a JSON string (of length around 8 lac, 800,000 characters) which I need to store in a Long Text Area field of size 1,31,072 (Big Object LTA field). Is there a way to compress the JSON string to fit into the field length?

Is there a way? Yes. Probably even several. For example, Run-Length encoding comes to mind. Apex doesn't offer that though, so you'd need to write the encoder/decoder yourself. It's also not guaranteed that you'd be able to get the 8:1 reduction you're looking for. Beyond that, this is an X-Y problem right now (you're asking about your attempted solution rather than about the problem itself). Why do you need to store the JSON? What problem does that solve for you? [Edit] your question to add those details.
